# Finding the best combination of elements with the max total parameter value

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I have 100 elements. Each element has 4 features A,B,C,D. Each feature is an integer.

I want to select 2 elements for each feature, so that I have selected a total of 8 distinct elements. I want to maximize the sum of the 8 selected features A,A,B,B,C,C,D,D.

A greedy algorithm would be to select the 2 elements with highest A, then the two elements with highest B among the remaining elements, etc. However, this might not be optimal, because the elements that have highest A could also have a much higher B.

Do we have an algorithm to solve such a problem optimally?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how & why we split the characters into 4 groups? It seems to have no bearing on the overall score.

Comment: Hi W.Lin, and welcome to StackOverflow! I'm afraid I have no idea what you are trying to achieve, and I suspect that others have the same problem. It would be benificial for you and those trying to help you if you read up on [How to ask][https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask]. Paticularly, generalization often makes it harder for us to help you. Therefore let us know what your characters are, what integer parameters they have, how they have to be split into groups. It will also be motivating (at least for me) to have a short overview on the problem you are trying to solve with this.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. As opposed to the previous two comments, I think the question is clear. It's an interesting problem.

Comment: OK, then let me ask more specifically: Like Dillon Davis, I wonder why we have to split the eight characters into four groups. Also, what do you mean with "four groups corresponding to the parameters"? What quantity do you want to maximize when you sort the eight characters into the four groups?

Comment: Ah, bold edit @Stef :) Would you mind adding that each of the 100 elements may only be chosen once? (I can not edit.) Does the new formulation fit your question, W.Lin?

Comment: I took the liberty of completely rewriting the question. @W.Lin, if you are unsatisfied with my edit, there is a "rollback" button somewhere to cancel my edit.

Comment: @Stef, and NerdOnTour
Thank you for elaborating my question, it seems to perfectly fit my intention.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved as a [minimum cost flow problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem). In particular, this is an [Assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem)

First of all, see that we only need the 8 best elements of each features, meaning 32 elements maximum. It should even be possible to cut the search space further (as if the 2 best elements of A is not one of the 6 best elements of any other feature, we can already assigne those 2 elements to A, and each other feature only needs to look at the first 6 best elements. If it's not clear why, I'll try to explain further).

Then we make the vertices S,T and Fa,Fb,Fc,Fd and E1,E2,...E32, with the following edge :

- for each vertex Fx, an edge from S to Fx with maximum flow 2 and a weight of 0 (as we want 2 element for each feature)
- for each vertex Ei, an edge from Fx to Ei if Ei is one of the top elements of feature x, with maximum flow 1 and weight equal to the negative value of feature x of Ei. (negative because the algorithm will find the minimum cost)
- for each vertex Ei, an edge from Ei to T, with maximum flow 1 and weight 0. (as each element can only be selected once)

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but It should work.

Comment: I'm not quite familiar with graph theory, but the Assignment problem gives me some hint. Let's say each element is like an agent, and each feature is like a task (the integer value of that feature is like its cost, in negative form though), so what I want to do can be converted to solving the Assignment problem twice because I need to pick 2 elements for each feature? That is, pick 4 elements first, and then pick another 4 elements from the remaining 96 elements.

Comment: @W.Lin Here is a formulation as an assignment problem: On the one side, take the 8 best elements for each feature. That's 32 elements or less, since one element might the in the best 8 for more than one feature. Call k the number of elements (k <= 32). Then on the other side, put 2 seats marked A, 2 seats marked B, 2 seats marked C, 2 seats marked D, and (k-8) seats marked "unused". Then every one of the k elements must be assigned to exactly one of the k seats, and conversely every seat must be assigned to one of the elements. That's an assignment problem.

Comment: If you pick 4 and 4 it would not be optimal. All 8 picks needs to happen at the same time. (imagine if in the 4 first picked, two have really high scores for feature A : only one would be assigned to A, where the optimal choice would be to assign both to A). I was wrong with the assignment problem though, this is a variant where each task needs 2 agents (or each agent can do 2 task, depends on how you want to model it).

Answer (score 1):

As suggested per @AloisChristen, this can be written as an assignment problem:

- On the one side, we select the 8 best elements for each feature; that's 32 elements or less, since one element might be in the best 8 for more than one feature;
- On the other side, we put 8 seats A,A,B,B,C,C,D,D
- Solve the resulting assignment problem.

Here the problem is solved using [scipy's `linear_sum_assignment` optimization function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html):

```py
from numpy.random import randint
from numpy import argpartition, unique, concatenate
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment

# PARAMETERS

n_elements = 100
n_features = 4
n_per_feature = 2

# RANDOM DATA

data = randint(0, 21, (n_elements, n_features))  # random data with integer features between 0 and 20 included

# SELECT BEST 8 CANDIDATES FOR EACH FEATURE

n_selected = n_features * n_per_feature
n_candidates = n_selected * n_features
idx = argpartition(data, range(-n_candidates, 0), axis=0)
idx = unique(idx[-n_selected:].ravel())
candidates = data[idx]
n_candidates = candidates.shape[0]

# SOLVE ASSIGNMENT PROBLEM

cost_matrix = -concatenate((candidates,candidates), axis=1)  # 8 columns in order ABCDABCD
element_idx, seat_idx = linear_sum_assignment(cost_matrix)
score = -cost_matrix[element_idx, seat_idx].sum()

# DISPLAY RESULTS

print('SUM OF SELECTED FEATURES: {}'.format(score))
for e,s in zip(element_idx, seat_idx):
    print('{:2d}'.format(idx[e]),
          'ABCDABCD'[s],
          -cost_matrix[e,s],
          data[idx[e]])
```

Output:

```
SUM OF SELECTED FEATURES: 160
 3 B 20 [ 5 20 14 11]
 4 A 20 [20  9  3 12]
 6 C 20 [ 3  3 20  8]
10 A 20 [20 10  9  9]
13 C 20 [16 12 20 18]
23 D 20 [ 6 10  4 20]
24 B 20 [ 5 20  6  8]
27 D 20 [20 13 19 20]
```