# How to optimize matches of objects with some constraints

Tags: excel

I don't even know if the Title makes sense. My coding experience is limited but there are often understandable examples if I can find them. I'm hoping that Excel can do this. Please point me the right direction, or tell me what words to use in my searches for help.

This basic example illustrates my need:

| cityname | temperature | humidity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hot City | high |  |
| Coldtown | low | rainy |
| Amazonville | high | rainy |

| person | sex | likes hot | likes humid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| joe | m | no |  |
| tim | m | yes | yes |
| bill | m | yes | no |
| jane | f | yes | no |
| mary | f | no | no |
| sue | f | yes | yes |

I want to come up with the best match for pairs of male/female couples, 3 couples living in the 3 cities, all as happy as possible with their preferences.

There may be several proposed answers (in a more complicated case), but here a reasonable result would look like:

joe+mary, in Coldtown
tim+sue, in Amazonville
bill+jane, in Hot City

It would be nice to constrain some matches, such as joe must be with sue, or joe must live in Coldtown.

How do I ask about this type of problem when searching on the web (what words to use)? Referring me to a basic Excel example would be wonderful!

Comment: Why Joe should be with Sue? What are rules? First you need to make rules and then covert it to formulas

Comment: From your response, I think I did not explain it well. Generally, there are NO RULES. We have a set of preferences and we are doing our best to meet those preferences. I fully expect that the solution won't be perfect. In SOME cases, we might have to say Joe must live in Coldtown -- but that can be a later concern. I don't know the right math words to describe this problem. In my words, I would say we are looking for a solution that optimizes preferences. I would assume this "need" is extremely common -- at least it has been in my life.

Comment: What is expected result for given dataset? Anyway seems like FILTER would come in handy.

Comment: To get "tim+sue, in Amazonville" and "bill+jane, in Hot City" you could FILTER opposite sex and same preferences. Same for a city. But I don't get why you put Mary in rainy city while she doesn't like humid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of problem is an [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem), and sort of the inverse of the related cost flow problems, which are subsets of graphing problems. Here's a good discussion, especially the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71203731/finding-the-best-combination-of-elements-with-the-max-total-parameter-value).

There are many ways to do this; here's how I would think about it.

First, you need to develop rules (as mentioned in a comment). This doesn't mean "Joe always lives in the city"; rather, it means you must have some programmatic way to compare outcomes. I would implement a score.

- Rule 1: each preference that is met gives +1 to that person's score, a preference missed gives 0 points. You could also have 'weighted' preferences (ie, getting 'hot' is worth two points, while getting 'humid' right is worth 1 point); these preference weights could be individual for each person, too.
- Rule 2: Each Couple must live in only one city, and each city can have only one couple (per your stated problem).
- Rule 3: Each couple is 1 male and 1 female, and one person can not be a part of two couples.
- Rule 4: We care about everyone, so most total points wins. (Instead of, say, Jane's happiness being twice as important as everyone elses, so we would multiply her points by two).

Now, we look at all possible combinations (rule 2&3), and compare the outcomes by finding inividual scores (rule 1) and adding them up (rule 4). This is a little tricky in basic Excel, but possible. [Power Query can do it too](https://exceloffthegrid.com/list-of-all-possible-combinations-using-power-query/).

If the first pair lives in a city we could call them P1F (pair 1 female), P1M (pair 1 male), and P1C (pair 1 city), etc., and you would add up the score for each person based on the city they were in to get a total score for the outcome. You want to end up with a list like this:

| P1F | P1M | P1C | P2F | P2M | P2C | P3F | P3M | P3C | Total Score For this Combo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jane | Joe | HotCity | Mary | Tim | Coldtown | Sue | Bill | Amazonville | `8 (2+1+1+1+2+1)` |
| Jane | Joe | HotCity | Mary | Bill | Coldtown | Sue | Tim | Amazonville | `7 (2+1+1+0+2+1)` |
| Jane | Tim | HotCity | Mary | Joe | Coldtown | Sue | Bill | Amazonville | `8 (2+1+1+1+2+1)` |
| Jane | Tim | HotCity | Mary | Bill | Coldtown | Sue | Joe | Amazonville | `6 (2+1+1+0+2+0)` |
| Jane | Bill | HotCity | Mary | Tim | Coldtown | Sue | Joe | Amazonville | `9 (2+2+2+1+2+0)` |
| Jane | Bill | HotCity | Mary | Joe | Coldtown | Sue | Tim | Amazonville | `11 (2+2+2+1+2+2)` |

There are more possible outcomes; this only shows those for which Jane is in HotCity, Mary in ColdTown, and Sue in Amazonville, I think there are 36 total combinations for your example but I might be off. In just the 6 outcomes examined above, the last one is clearly the best, while the 4th pairing is the worst. But by comparing all 36 possible outcomes, you will see, eg, many ties (outcomes 1 and 3 are equally good); there may not be any one best answer.

Edit: And as we change the rules, we get different possible outcomes, and different scores for those outcomes. EG -- what if more than 1 couple could live in a city? What if people could just live where they wanted (no couples)? What if Bill doesn't care where *he* lives, but cares that his partner is happy (Bills score = partner's score)? What if Mary hates getting rained on with the fury of 1,000 suns (-100000 points if Mary is in a rainy city)?

The actual comparison is usually pretty easy (most points wins), but determining all the possible outcomes is the tricky part!

Comment: Now that I know what this type of problem is called, I think it lends itself to a solution with Excel's Solver. I will be looking into that, but if anyone can show that I would sure appreciate it!

Comment: You could set up a solver with six decision variables (3 woman, 3 men) in columns, where each column is a city, with constraints integer 1-3, and all different (thus, find permutations). Might be a little fiddly to get men and women to match. Then a set of cells that would calculate the score of each person in that position, and add it up to an objective cell. But I prefer doing like above: there may not be *one* best answer, and seeing all outcomes is more informative.